# Projection of force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, statics

[image]

So to find the projection along the cable in question 124 we used CA (not AC). Why?
I thought that we always start from the end point of the Force, which is AC and not CA.

Comment: It is probably just a convention that you prefer to calculate a positive tension force along a cable, as opposed to a negative compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought that we always start from the end point of the Force, which is AC and not CA

Well, be careful with saying "always". It is always just a choice. What you choose to do is different from case to case.

The force vector $\vec F$ is fixed in this case, but the position vector (let's call it $\vec r$) that they want you to project $\vec F$ onto is up to their choice. They choose the position vector from C to A instead of the vector from A to C. That is just their choice of whatever reason they might have.

As @NeilSlater comments, turning such a vector 180 degress around just changes the sign of the projection. Mathematically, this is true because the projection length equals the mathematical dot product:

$$\text{Projection length:}\quad\vec F \cdot \vec r_{CA}=F \; r_{CA}\cos(\theta)$$

The $\theta$ is the angle between them, and this angle is 180 degrees larger for a vector going the other way. This gives a minus-sign on the cosine, $\cos(\theta+180^\circ)=-\cos(\theta)$, because of the way cosine is defined in the unit circle.